# DataGrid doesn't get updated after updating ObservableCollection that's bound to it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a pretty serious problem for a few days that I can't solve.

I have a XAML window with a datagrid which `ItemsSource` is bound to a static property of a custom type that contains an `ObservableCollection` of another custom type.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TheFaceBook.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TheProject"
    Title="MainWindow" MinHeight="253" MinWidth="882" xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="632" d:DesignWidth="933" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MainWindow x:Key="mainWindow"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Start" Height="33" Margin="0,28,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnStart_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="97" />
    <DataGrid Margin="12,110,12,42" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentUser.TaggedImages}"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding AbsoluteURL}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FacebookURL}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

code behind property:

```
private static User m_CurrentUser;
public static User CurrentUser
{
    get { return MainWindow.m_CurrentUser; }
    set
    {
        MainWindow.m_CurrentUser = value;
    }
}
```

user class:

```
private ObservableCollection <Picture> m_TaggedImages;

#endregion
#region Properties

public ObservableCollection<Picture> TaggedImages
{
    get { return m_TaggedImages; }
    set 
    { 
        m_TaggedImages = value;
    }
}
```

picture class:

```
public class Picture : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
    private string m_URL;
    private string m_AbsoluteURL;
    private List<User> m_TaggedUsers;

    public List<User> TaggedUsers
    {
        get { return m_TaggedUsers; }
        set 
        {
            m_TaggedUsers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TaggedUsers");
        }
    }

    public string AbsoluteURL
    {
        get { return m_AbsoluteURL; }
        set
        {
            m_AbsoluteURL = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AbsoluteURL");
        }
    }

    public string URL
    {
        get { return m_URL; }
        set
        {
            m_URL = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("URL");
        }
    }
}
```

the code who adds a picture to the TaggedImagse:

inside the bgwDoWork:

bgwPictureFinder.ReportProgress(0, pic);

bgwProgressChanged:

```
static void bgwPictureFinder_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ProgressPercentage == 0)
    {
        Picture pic = (Picture)e.UserState;
        MainWindow.CurrentUser.TaggedImages.Add(pic);
    }
}
```

when I add to the `MainWindow.CurrentUser.TaggedImages` manually from some other `backgroundworker` it is working great, but when adding from `bgwPictureFinder_ProgressChanged` it adds the picture to the `MainWindow.CurrentUser.TaggedImages observableCollection` but not updating the UI to show the image.

I just can't figure it out what is causing this problem.

Comment: Do you check for exceptions in the Bgw (ie in Completed) ?

Comment: Are you sure you are adding the pic? Why if (e.ProgressPercentage == 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss that on your code exemple:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   var handlers = PropertyChanged;
   if (handlers != null)
   {
      handlers(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

And for your Binding, I use the Two Way Mode:

```
{Binding..., Mode=TwoWay}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if WPF upto (v 4.0) supports Databinding to Static Properties.
This feature was added in .NET 4.5. [Check this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588.aspx#static_properties)

**Quotes from What's New in WPF Version 4.5:**

> **Binding to static properties**
>
> You can use static properties as the source of a data binding. The
>   data binding engine recognizes when the property's value changes if a
>   static event is raised. For example, if the class SomeClass defines a
>   static property called MyProperty, SomeClass can define a static event
>   that is raised when the value of MyProperty changes. The static event
>   can use either of the following signatures.

```
public static event EventHandler MyPropertyChanged;
public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
```

> Note that in the first case, the class exposes a static event named
>   PropertyNameChanged that passes EventArgs to the event handler. In the
>   second case, the class exposes a static event named
>   StaticPropertyChanged that passes PropertyChangedEventArgs to the
>   event handler. A class that implements the static property can choose
>   to raise property-change notifications using either method.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it has to do something with the order you initialize new objects. Such as TaggedImages List and actual CurrentUser property. It's really simple to check. Look into "Debugging bindings" and see what happens.

and I would add OnPropertyChanged("TaggedImages") too. Yes, the add/remove of observableCollection is already implemented but I dont think there is any way WPF is gonna be able to tell when the actual collection reference changes without OnPropertyChanged.